# $http get return html source code angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, cakephp

I saw one thread about that on the forum but there was no answers... I explain my problem,I want to validate my form with angularsjs and connect so I send a http request on submit,and in my method login(i use cake php) I have an echo jsonencode who print a array that contain errors ect but http return the json and the html source code.I tried with .post it work but it's more slower
(sorry for my bad english).
here is my code:

```js
(function () {
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', ['ngMessages']).controller('formController',function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.formData = {};
      $scope.connecter=false;
      $scope.submitted = false;
      $scope.connexion="";
      $scope.formData.emessage = "Veuillez entrer vos identifiants";
      
      var posting = $.post( 'login', $.param($scope.formData),function( data )  
      { 
        if (!data.success) {
            
      
        } 
        else {
            $scope.connexion="connecter";
            $scope.formData.emessage = data.message;
            $scope.submitted = true;
            $scope.connecter=true;
            alert('connecter');
            }
      },"json");
      

      $scope.processForm =   function(){ 
      
        var posting =$http({
                      method: 'POST',
                      url: 'login',
                      data: $.param($scope.formData),
                      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                      responseType :"json",

                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        alert(response.success);
                        $scope.connexion="connecter";
                        $scope.formData.emessage = "connecter";
                        $scope.submitted = true;
                        $scope.connecter=true;
                        alert('connecter');


                      }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert(response);
                      });

    };
});
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" >

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- If you delete this meta tag World War Z will become a reality -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?= $title_for_layout; ?></title>

   
    <?= $this->Html->css('foundation'); ?>
    <?= $this->Html->css('app'); ?>
    <?= $this->Html->script('vendor/modernizr'); ?>
      <?= $this->Html->script('vendor/jquery'); ?>
    <?= $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js'); ?>   
    <?= $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-messages.js'); ?>  

    <?= $this->Html->script('form'); ?>

  </head>
  <body   ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController"> 


   

    <div class="wrapper"  >
      <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal tiny" data-reveal aria-labelledby="login or sign up"  role="dialog">
        <div id="box"  >
           <h3 id="successds" ng-class="connexion" ng-show="submitted" >{{formData.emessage}}</h3>
              <div id="eusername" ng-messages="UserLoginForm.lusername.$error" >
                <p ng-message="minlength">Votre Nom d'utilisateur est invalide</p>
                <p ng-message="maxlength">Votre Nom d'utilisateur est invalide</p>
                <p ng-message="required">Vous devez entrez votre nom d'utilisateur</p>
              </div>
            <?= $this->Form->create('User',array(
            'default'=>false,
            'novalidate'=>'true',
            'name' =>'UserLoginForm',
            'ng-click' =>'processForm()'
            ));?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('username',array(
            'label' =>false,          
            'ng-model'=>'formData.username',
            'ass'=> 'btes',
            'name'=>'lusername',
            'ng-minlength'=> 5,
            'ng-maxlength' => 15,         
            'placeholder'=>"Nom d'utilisateur"
            )); ?>       
            <?= $this->Form->input('password',array(
            'label' =>false,
            'class'=> 'btes',
            'name'=>'lpassword',
            'ng-model'=> 'formData.password',
            'ng-minlength'=>8,
            'placeholder'=>"Mot de passe")); ?>
            <div id="epass" ng-messages="UserLoginForm.lpassword.$error" >
              <p ng-message="minlength">Votre Mot de passe est invalide</p>
            </div> 
            <?= $this->Form->end(array('label'=>'Se connecter', 'class'=>'button small success round','ng-disabled'=>'UserLoginForm.$invalid')); ?>
            <div class="signupe">
              <?=$this->Html->link("Mot de passe oubliée ?",array(
              'controller' => 'users', 
              'action' => 'lost')); ?>
            </div>        
            <div class="signupe">
              <p><span class="t">Pas encore membre ?</span> <?=$this->Html->link("S'inscrire",array(
              'controller' => 'users', 
              'action' => 'signup')); ?></p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?= $this->fetch('content'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump');?>
    <?= $this->Html->script('foundation.min'); ?>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue should be that `php` code is not working proper. In controller request method is `post` which will call `onClick` for login but UI is not rendering properly so it should be solved first.

I'm not php developer but `$http` gives hint that it is not error related to `angularjs`

I'm not getting why you have used `$http` of angularjs for `login` and `$.post` of jQuery for same `login` request. If app is angular then it is better to use `$http` and use request only **once** not twice or more.

Comment: Thank you but It return me the same things I tried http://localhost/site/users/login and http://localhost:8080/site/users/login ... blocked me.I used that because it work so i can compare request.

Comment: It may be possible that your php code is not rendering proper. there may be possibility of error in php

Comment: maybe i just add my function login i use cakephp do you want full code of controller ?

Comment: Yes thank you for your help but it work with .post it return me only json but with $http it return me json and html code source so it could be a problem with cakephp ?

Comment: If it working for `jQuery post` and not working with `$http` then the issue is configuring `$http` request. Not cakephp issue...

Answer (score 0):

yes but when I go on http://localhost/site/users/login it show me the view of login so maybe the probleme it's here cause when I'm looking for xhr request I see the response of login for $http is the json_encode of data and all of my default layout with the fetch content..